# Chromecast always buffering

Tags: wireless-networking, router, chromecast

I have a Chromecast device, Samsung UE40EH5300 TV and Sky broadband with the Sky Hub router.

The problem I am having is that when I am watching anything on Chromecast I get constant buffering. An example application would be iPlayer.

It is not an internet bandwidth issue as I get around 15Mbps and could easily watch something on iPlayer using the Smart TV function or on any of my other devices without any issues at all.

The Chromecast device has line-of-sight to the router.

Any ideas on anything I can do to help stop the contant need for buffering?

Comment: Is the TV it self connected to the network and if so wired or wifi?

Comment: Its wired, but I have no issue buffering from any other device, wired or WIFI.

Comment: Can you place another wifi device right next to the chromecast and does it still work fine?

Comment: Yes, a WIFI device, such as my Tablet or Laptop, when next to my chromecast device, works completely fine.

Comment: I had a similar issue with chromecast and found it had to do with noise in my broadband through the coax part.  We had cable tv with multiple splitters to get to each room.  I removed the splitters to improve the signal to the modem and for some reason this improved the chromecast.